# Apache: Redirect entire virtual host to a URL

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

Centos 5.2, Apache 2.2.3

I want to configure Apache to redirect any URL under mail.mydomain.com to the single URL https://mail.google.com/a/mydomain.com

How can I set this up with Apache?  I have

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

but I'm not sure how to actually use this and I can't find a really simple example; I assume I set up a new virtual host with some form of rewrite directive, but how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put a .htaccess in the document root and then put this in it :

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule $ https://mail.google.com/a/mydomain.com [L]`

or you can do the above in the VHost definition.

Comment: Perfect - I did this in the vhost definition.